# How to list a subset of files in several directories?

Tags: linux, command-line, directory-listing

I'm starting to pick up Linux. I have one directory called `class03` with five directories in it:

```
_html
html
dothtml
images
123
```

I need a one-line command that lists all files with `-01`, `-02` and `-03` in the file name in those directories.

I can get all the files to list with the command:

```
ls _html/ html/ dothtml/ images/
```

When i try to put the restrictions it still lists without the restriction and errors with the `*-0[123]`

I tried:

```
ls *-0[123] * _html/ html/ dothtml/ images/
```

and:

```
ls _html/ html/ dothtml/ images/ * -0[123] *
```

So what do I need to do to make the code work in one command?

Comment: By the way, if you want to list all the files in, say, the `_html` and `html` directories, it's good enough to say `ls _htlm html` -- you don't need to type `/` at the end of each directory name.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other directories, you can use just

```
ls */*-0[123]*
```

If there are more directories you want to exclude, you can use the brace expansion:

```
ls {{,_,dot}html,images,123}/*-0[123]*
```

Comment: now if i wanted to move those files would i just use that same command replace ls to mv

Comment: @brianfox: Sure. But be careful if files with the same name exist in different source directories, you will get `mv: will not overwrite just-created`.